# Tuple v/s StaticVectors in Julia

Tags: data-structures, julia

If I understand correctly, then as tuples are immutable in Julia, they must also be stack allocated (similar to StaticVectors). So there should be not any advantage of using StaticVectors in place of Tuples when I am dealing with small vectors say, a length 3 vector for coordinates of a particle. Can someone highlight the advantages of using StaticVectors in such cases. And more broadly what will be the use cases where I would possible want to choose using one over the other?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe StaticVectors support linesr algebra and are AbstractArray subtypes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The raw performance is similar, since StaticArrays are built on tuples. The point of StaticArrays is all the functionality, the linear algebra, the solvers, sorting, the mutable arrays, etc.

Tuples are a barebones data collection with barely any mathematical structure. That's fine as far as it goes, but StaticArrays has done most of the work you would have to do yourself with tuples.